# Measuring WCF network traffic

Tags: silverlight, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I have a VS2010 solution with a Silverlight frontend and a WCF service as backend. I want to measure the WCF communication network traffic. Is there a tool for this? I want to know the number of network packages and network package sizes. I only want to measure the WCF communication packages, not any web site content traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WCF monitoring there are special performance counters available by default in the PERMON.EXE program. Read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/09/07/how-to-use-performance-counters-to-diagnose-performance-of-wcf-applications.aspx for details on how to enable monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

I now use Fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com This is a great tool.